# React Native: Export Compliance Information - HTTPS Calls

Tags: ios, react-native, axios

I'm publishing my first react native app, and I got to these questions:
[image]
[image]

If I'm making basic https calls through axios to my api on an aws server, do I have to answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, you should say yes for both questions see here https://www.cocoanetics.com/2017/02/itunes-connect-encryption-info/